# How can I have both file download and redirection in for submit?

Tags: forms, 9

I have this form submit:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

//  File download
    $sFileName = 'JdP-Adhesion.pdf';
    $sFileNameWithPath = 'sites/default/files/' . $sFileName;
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($sFileNameWithPath);
    $response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $sFileName
    );
    $form_state->setResponse($response);

//  Redirection to front page
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromRoute('<front>'));
    return;
}
```

I can't make the two sets of code work together.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I don’t think this is possible.

Comment: I agree, I don't think it's possible, as the download is a response, and the redirect is a different response. You could redirect to a page that also forces the download maybe.

Comment: I think @Jaypan comment is right. It is possible to redirect to a page which then starts the download. That also means the page to which users are redirected must be able to start the download; redirecting to a page provided by Drupal core would not start the file download.